# I have a xml file which is having lots of special characters which I need to find out and put the distinct list of those into a text file

Tags: xml, utf-8, automated-tests

I have a xml file. I need to find out the special characters from that xml file except A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and the following list of symbols. Is there a way to automate this or should I be looking for a utf-8 editor?

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

using notepadd++ find special characters in this list helped me a bit: http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

if you have a better solution I would be happy to adopt. Thanks